# Why did the prophet take Counsel of his companions in martial and social affairs?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, islamic-basis

When the Holy Prophet was in contact with the Almighty Allah and he was the most wise and knowledgeable why did he need to take counsel of his companions in martial and social affairs?

Answer (score 3):

Because Allah commanded him to do so:

> #### وشاورهم في الأمر
>
> and consult them in the affairs
>
> <sup>— [Quran 3:159](https://quran.com/3/159?translations=18)</sup>

According to scholarly opinions documented in [Tafsir Qurtubi](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura3-aya159.html) and [Tafsir Baghawi](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/baghawy/sura3-aya159.html), the Prophet was free of any *need* for their advice because of revelation, however Allah still commanded him to seek their counsel to:

- honor and engage them
- to prevent them from feeling distressed and alienated or harboring reservations
- to teach them about the importance of consultation so that they would follow the precedent set by the Prophet in this regard.

Comment: Subhanallah well answered!

Answer (score -2):

Allah (swt) only spoke to him directly once (command for prayer) other then that he was in contact with Him through Jibreel . The prophet knew when he should consult The most wise and when to consult his companions.